# How can I access hubot without adding hubot with each message?

Tags: javascript, facebook-messenger, hubot

I am developing a facebook messenger bot using hubot & hubot-fb adapter. 
All the basic setup is done & is working perfectly. But, in order to chat with the bot I need to add hubot with all the commands. In case of facebook chats, it doesn't make much sense. A current chat looks something like this:

```
user: hubot ping
bot: PONG
user: hubot the rules
bot: 0. A robot may not harm humanity, or, by inaction, allow humanity to come to harm.
1. A robot may not injure a human being or, through inaction, allow a human being to come to harm.
2. A robot must obey any orders given to it by human beings, except where such orders would conflict with the First Law.
3. A robot must p
```

however, I want my bot to be accessible without using the "hubot" with all the messenges. How do I achieve that?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the 'hear' method, instead of the 'respond' method.

Hubot has two methods for how it interacts with with messages:

**hear** - This is called whenever text in a message room matches a given regex.  The robot's name is not used in this case. Example:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.hear /ping/i, (res) ->
    res.send "PONG"
```

The following messages would cause the robot.hear callback to be called:

- ping
- how do I ping the server

Note: the regex in this case is very simplistic and could be modified so the callback is not called for the "how do I ping the server" case.

**respond** - this is only called when text matches a given regex AND is immediately preceded by the robot's name or alias. Example:

```
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /ping/i, (res) ->
    res.reply "PONG"
```

The following messages would cause the robot.respond callback to be called:

- @Hubot ping
- Hubot ping

It would NOT be called for the following, since the robot's name is not used.

- ping
- how do I ping the server

See the [Hubot scripting documentation](https://hubot.github.com/docs/scripting/#hearing-and-responding) for more details.

Comment: Hi, 

I just found an easier way to do that.
While starting the bot in command line (procfile in case of heroku) you can provide a name switch. Just pass an empty string in that and it works perfectly. 

    hubot -n ""

Thanks for the answer :)